# SQL Query to get all locations(lat/lng) within a certain distance from a given location(lat/lng)

Tags: c#, sql, math, maps

Given a database of places with Latitude and Longitude locations, such as 30.706557, 76.733588. How would I find all locations within a given distance of a specific location?

It doesn't seem very efficient to select all locations from the DB and then go through them one by one, getting the distance from the starting location to see if they are within the specified distance. Is there a good way to narrow down the initially selected locations from the DB?

I have just found this query:

```
    SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT *,(((acos(sin((@latitude*pi()/180)) * sin((Latitude*pi()/180))+cos((@latitude*pi()/180)) * cos((Latitude*pi()/180)) * cos(((@longitude - Longitude)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344) as distance FROM Distances) t
WHERE distance <= @distance
```

Help me to understand and to implement it, if this is the right way. Thank you.

Comment: What DB?  SQL Server has a geography type that has a distance method you can use.

Comment: Using Lat-Long as unique columns you can at least determine a bounding "box" around your location to narrow it down.

Comment: Thoughts: 1) use postgreSQL's postgis, 2) create table with 3D data from 2D data and use `(x-x0)^2 + (y-y0)^2 + (z-z0)^2` as your function (still ugly, but faster)-- obviously, you'll need to modify the condition, 3) use the approximation that distance is proportional to difference in latitude + `(difference in longitude) times cosine(latitude)`

Comment: @barrycarter thanks man, will try this asap.